# how to get list of collection {Mongodb} in php using 'new MongoDB\Driver\Manager' driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to get all collection of monogoDB using php.

I am getting only one collection using bellow code.

```
<?php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$listdatabases = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["listCollections" => 1]);
$res = $manager->executeCommand("mydatabasename", $listdatabases);
$collections = current($res->toArray());
print_r($collections);

stdClass Object
(
    [name] => collectionname
    [type] => collection
    [options] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [info] => stdClass Object
        (
            [readOnly] => 
            [uuid] => MongoDB\BSON\Binary Object
                (
                    [data] => �����B���tqIB
                    [type] => 4
                )

        )

    [idIndex] => stdClass Object
        (
            [v] => 2
            [key] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [_id] => 1
                )

            [name] => _id_
            [ns] => collectionname
        )

)
```

## But i want all collections list.

MongoDB version  : 3.4.16

Php version : 7.1

Answer (score -1):

You just need to remove current from

```
$collections = current($res->toArray());
```

You will get all the collections. It should be

```
$collections = $res->toArray();
```